# JENKINS: parsing POM error for Maven project: FATAL Non-Readable POM

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Below is my POM.xml and it works well locally. but when I run it from Jenkins I see below error.

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/root/.jenkins/workspace/LocalProject
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /Users/jaydippatel/Documents/Jaydip/GitHub/BackUp Projects/bse-integration-salesforce-TestNG/pom.xml: /Users/jaydippatel/Documents/Jaydip/GitHub/BackUp Projects/bse-integration-salesforce-TestNG/pom.xml (Operation not permitted) @ 

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:397)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:370)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:340)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1330)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1124)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1173)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1156)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:516)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1889)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:100)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:433)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Build advance settings are set as below:
Maven Validation level: DEFAULT
Settings File: Use Default maven settings
Global Settings file: User default maven global settings

POM.xml is as below.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>lyft</groupId>
    <artifactId>homepage</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>



    <name>homepage</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <cucumber.version>6.10.2</cucumber.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.18</lombok.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.09</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    
        <plugins>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target> -->
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <parallel>methods</parallel> -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>testng.xml</suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!-- <useUnlimitedThread>true</useUnlimitedThread>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount> -->
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>Salesforce</projectName>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                            <prallelTesting>false</prallelTesting>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <classpathPrefix>.</classpathPrefix>
                                    <mainClass>test.TestRunner</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is "locally" a WIN PC and "in Jenkins" a linux box (`/var/root/.jenkins`)  ? Linux does not handle spaces well: "`.../Jaydip/GitHub/BackUp Projects/bse-integration-salesforce-TestNG/`". Also not clear why it says: "Building in workspace `/var/root/.jenkins/workspace/LocalProject`" but attempting to read the POM from: "`/Users/jaydippatel/Documents/Jaydip/`"; I'd expect your source to be inside the the workspace folder.

Comment: Judging from the error you are on linux, does the file have the correct permissions so that it is actually readable by the process that Jenkins runs with?

Comment: The issue looks like `(Operation not permitted) @` ....

Comment: @Ian W Yes, I am on macOS. also my workspace is still in local file system and I have provided path for pom.xml as /Users/jaydippatel/Documents/Jaydip/GitHub/BackUp Projects/bse-integration-salesforce-TestNG/pom.xml thats why its trying to read it from users directory.

Comment: @M. Deinum: Yes I checked the file permissions and all users on machine has read/write access if thats what you were asking.

Comment: Why isn't Jenkins just running maven from the root of your project? I assume the file system on your mac isn't the same as Jenkins so why should jenkins be able to access in that specific location?

Comment: @M. Deinum - I am not following 100% what you are pointing out. but I am trying this for first time on Mac machine so guide me about what you mean and what could I try.

Comment: Most Jenkins users locate their source and pom.xml in a repo, clone the repo into workspace as part of the job and run within the context of the workspace.